# MS Access Calculate seconds by hour

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in an Access Database where the only information that i have is:

```
start_time (date & time);
end_time (date & time);
duration (int, seconds);
```

What i need to have in my output is how many time spent in each hour bracket.

One example:

```
start_time: 2016/07/01 09:00:00
end_time: 2016/07/03 09:00:00
```

in this example, the pretended output is:

```
Date      | Hour | Duration
2016/07/01   9     3600
2016/07/01   10    3600
2016/07/01   11    3600
2016/07/01   12    3600
   ...       ...    ...
2016/07/03   8     3600
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `duration (int, seconds);` column? Does it play a role in the calculation?

Comment: Hi Andre, there's no purpose using that column. Duration field is the difference between end_time - start_time

Answer (score 2):

If you only count in full hours, this will do:

```
PARAMETERS 
    StartDate DateTime, 
    EndDate DateTime;
SELECT 
    DateValue(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])) AS [Date], 
    Hour(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])) AS [Hour], 
    DateDiff("s",
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]),
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1,[StartDate])) AS Duration
FROM 
    MsysObjects AS Uno, 
    MsysObjects AS Deca
GROUP BY 
    DateValue(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])), 
    Hour(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])), 
    DateDiff("s",
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]),
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1,[StartDate])), DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])
HAVING 
    DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])<=[EndDate];
```

**Edit:**

You can include your table (Durations) directly:

```
SELECT 
    DateValue(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])) AS [Date], 
    Hour(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])) AS [Hour], 
    DateDiff("s",
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]),
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1,[StartDate])) AS Duration
FROM 
    MsysObjects AS Uno, 
    MsysObjects AS Deca, 
    Durations
WHERE 
    DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])<=[EndDate]
GROUP BY 
    DateValue(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])), 
    Hour(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])), 
    DateDiff("s",
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]),
        DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1,[StartDate]));
```

**To respect minutes and seconds:**

```
SELECT 
    DateValue(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])) AS [Date], 
    Hour(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])) AS [Hour], 
    DateDiff("s",
        IIf(DateDiff("h",[StartDate],DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]))=0,
            [StartDate],
            DateValue([StartDate])+TimeSerial(Hour([StartDate])+10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),0,0)),
        IIf(DateDiff("h",[EndDate],DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]))=0,
            [EndDate],
            DateValue([StartDate])+TimeSerial(Hour([StartDate])+10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1,0,0))) AS Duration
FROM 
    MsysObjects AS Uno, 
    MsysObjects AS Deca, 
    Durations
WHERE 
    DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])<[EndDate]
GROUP BY 
    DateValue(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])), 
    Hour(DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate])), 
    DateDiff("s",
        IIf(DateDiff("h",[StartDate],DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]))=0,
            [StartDate],
            DateValue([StartDate])+TimeSerial(Hour([StartDate])+10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),0,0)),
        IIf(DateDiff("h",[EndDate],DateAdd("h",10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10),[StartDate]))=0,
            [EndDate],
            DateValue([StartDate])+TimeSerial(Hour([StartDate])+10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10)+Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)+1,0,0)));
```

Comment: that is perfect! One last question, how can i relate this piece of code with my table (let's call it logintime), where i have the start and end dates.

Comment: thanks, i am almost there. Now what i get is the durations just like i want, but whenever i dont have time between x and y hour, it gives me 3600 automatically (it should appear zero). For instance, if the last interaction was untill 19:00, from 19:00 to next day i will have 3600 in each hour with your query. Can i change it to 0 (zero)? Thanks again for your patience :)

Comment: First, I modified the query's WHERE to leave out zero entries - see edit.

Comment: Second, I can't see why a full hour should be different from 3600 seconds. That was what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to add the table that i want and its running. However, i may not be clear when i asked the first question.

What i want is the duration breakdown by hour. And the query you're giving to me will return always 3600 as a duration (no matter what time is in start and end date).

This is a real example of 1 record that i have in my table:

```
campaign    agent   start_time              end_time
279          542    23/05/2016  17:05:21    24/05/2016 09:58:54
```

With this record, what i want is to know this:

```
date        hour duration
23/05/2016  17   3279
23/05/2016  18   3600
23/05/2016  19   3600
23/05/2016  20   3600
23/05/2016  21   3600
23/05/2016  22   3600
23/05/2016  23   3600
24/05/2016  0    3600
24/05/2016  1    3600
24/05/2016  2    3600
24/05/2016  3    3600
24/05/2016  4    3600
24/05/2016  5    3600
24/05/2016  6    3600
24/05/2016  7    3600
24/05/2016  8    3600
24/05/2016  9    3534
```

Please note that in first and last row i have the difference between start_time and the exact next hour.

Comment: OK, you didn't mention originally, but see edit. It works down to a duration of one or zero seconds and (as is) up to 100 hours.